# Rails app deploy users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm working on deploying my Rails app with Capistrano and the deploy is failing as it `cannot create directory`.

I have two users on my server:- root and deploy.

Capistrano is using the deploy user.

I have told Capistrano to deploy the app to /var/rails_apps/

It's /var/rails_apps/ that it cannot create a directory in.

What user should own that folder? root or deploy?

The server has nginx on it so I guess the site will run as www-data which looks to be nginx's user but I'm not sure what other areas should be owned by? Any clarification on this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deploy` should own that folder.  Nginx is just your web server, it is going to proxy requests to your application, which is likely running as a `unicorn` process (should run as `deploy`).